Installing kwin window manager isn't working
When I run the command:
sudo apt install kwin-x11 --no-install-recommends

it says this:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
   libkf5newstuff5 : Depends on: libkf5newstuffcore5 (= 5.92.0-0ubuntu1) but 5.92.0-0ubuntu1.1 should be installed
E: Unable to resolve issues, you have withheld broken packages.


You should always provide your Ununtu version when asking. Did you run sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade prior to your install command?

Check your sources & ensure you're not missing any; as the package is available libkf5newstuff5 | 5.92.0-0ubuntu1.1 | jammy-updates/universe  | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x so start with sudo apt update & ensure everything is good.  If you've got the correct libkf5newstuff5 | 5.92.0-0ubuntu1.1 | jammy-updates/universe  | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x you won't have that issue... so check you've not put holds on your system creating this issue.

In general, when apt says something about broken packages, you should sudo apt install -f (short for —fix-broken)
